# Wordpress site malfunctions when server disk is full

Tags: mysql, wordpress

My company has some private servers for web development.
The server has storage space of 600GB, but at times it runs out of disk space.

At such situations one of our websites using wordpress malfunctions and some of its features can't be accessed.

Can any one tell what is the possible cause for this & how it can be prevented?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: There could be a million reasons why the server disk is full - the server administrator is the person who should know more about this.

Comment: thanks for the your concern @Pekka , but ,m more concerned with WP malfunctioning rather than "why server disk is full"...

Comment: You *should* be concerned with the disk being full. You need some disk space to operate a web site, there's no way around it.

Comment: Again thanks for your concern @Pekka, but since its a site used for internal [within organization] purposes we are more concerned with resolving the issue of malfunctioning. 

Also the site is having some news articles only so i think rendering them should not be problematic even when the disk if full ??   

P.S. We know why disk space gets filled [lots of test/development instances run on same server]

Comment: Fair enough and the downvote isn't mine, but as explained in my answer, there is no way to fix the malfunctioning without freeing up some space. Web sites need some disk space to work even when they do not write anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> At such situations one of our websites using wordpress malfunctions and some of its features can't be accessed.

That's what happens when the disk is full - nothing we can do about that. Temporary files can no longer be created, including session files that are necessary to track whether a user is logged in or not. MySQL may need to write temporary data even when doing only a SELECT. The web server may need some swap space on the hard disk in peak times. etc. etc.

> I'm more concerned with WP malfunctioning rather than "why server disk is full".

That won't work. You need to fix the source of the problem, and that is the server's disk filling up. You can't make Wordpress work despite the disk being full.

Comment: _Temporary files can no longer be created, including session files that are necessary to track whether a user is logged in or not_ makes sense.. point i see... Thanks @Pekka

Answer (score 0):

It could be down to so many things, probably not at WordPress level. With no disk space apache can't write it's access/error logs, sessions can't be written by PHP, MySQL can't write and so on.

The only answer applicable to you at this stage is to stop maxing out the disk space.

Comment: is it possible that SELECT statements are causing MySql errors when disk is full ??

Comment: Probably not, anything could be causing disk errors, and it's impossible to tell as your server won't be able to write error logs. Bottom line is that your problem is server/disk space management.